# Criptografia simétrica swift

Tags: string, ios, swift, xcode, criptografia

Sou novo no swift, e gostaria de criptografar uma string, usando algum algoritmo de criptografia simétrica para que seja possível com a mesma chave descriptografar.
Gostaria de saber como pode ser feito isso na linguagem Swift.

Comment: Primeiro mostre o que você tentou, esperava que acontecesse e o que deu errado e a sua pergunta. Não é assim que funciona esse site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atualizado: Encontrei uma biblioteca que faz isso: https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift

e o código para resolver esse problema:

```
let input = NSData()
let encrypted = try! input.encrypt(AES(key: "secret0key000000", iv:"0123456789012345"))

let input: [UInt8] = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
input.encrypt(AES(key: "secret0key000000", iv:"0123456789012345", blockMode: .CBC))
```